# the factory value is changed to be null in controller randomly, however I injected it to controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, inject

I have an controller called `myController` as the following:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('myController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'myService',
 function ($rootScope, $scope, myService) { 
     $scope.myService = myService;

     $rootScope.$on('kpi:submit', function (event, data) {
            $window.sessionStorage['prevCall'] = JSON.stringify(data.prevCall);
            $window.sessionStorage['currCall'] = JSON.stringify(data.currentCall);
            $window.sessionStorage['nextCall'] = JSON.stringify(data.nextCall);

            myService.prevCall = $scope.prevCall = data.prevCall;
            myService.currentCall = $scope.currentCall = data.currentCall;
            myService.nextCall = $scope.nextCall = data.nextCall;
     });
}]);
```

And The `myService` factory, as the following:

```
'use strict';

app.factory('myService', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {     
        this.currentCall;
        this.prevCall;
        this.nextCall;

        // some function
        return {
            myFunction : myFunction
        };
}]);
```

The `kpi:submit` is called, when I click on `Submit` button. It's working well, but sometimes I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'prevCall' of null
```

So, Why the `myService` factory is changed to `null` suddenly, any suggested solution, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous function you're passing into the `$rootScope.$broadcast` does not have a reference to myService.

Either inject into your function:

```
function (event, data, myService)
```

Keep on using $scope:

```
$scope.myService.prevCall = $scope.prevCall = data.prevCall;
```

Can also use bind:

```
 $rootScope.$on('kpi:submit', function (event, data) {

 }.bind(myService));
```

Or [Angular.bind(var, function);](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind)